# Winmerge not in the context menu of everything tool

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, winmerge

I use this tool [everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) to search files.
In windows xp, I was able to search files and then use context menu for winmerge, tortoisesvn etc.
Now I have started using windows 7, everything works fine here only issue is I only get the basic menu not the installed applications' menu like winmerge, tortoisesvn etc.

Comment: You probably need to reinstall the programs which add context menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with both winmerge and tortoisesvn on my laptop (windows 7).
I installed tortoisesvn 32 bit version along with 64 bit (which I already had.)
After installing tortoisesvn 32 bit, context menu for tortoise started showing up in everything and phped nusphere.

For winmerge, they have a single version for both 32 and 64, so same trick didn't work !!

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Winmerge has the same installer for x86/32 bit and 64 bit.

To make it work with the Everything tool:

Uninstall Winmerge. Downloaded the zip version (not the installer, http://downloads.sourceforge.net/winmerge/WinMerge-2.14.0-exe.zip), extract it.

Then edit the "register.bat" (with notepad), and changed the 64 bit entries to use the old shell extension ...

```
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86"   Set DLLPATH=%~dp0%ShellExtensionU.dll
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "AMD64" Set DLLPATH=%~dp0%ShellExtensionX64.dll
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "IA64"  Set DLLPATH=%~dp0%ShellExtensionX64.dll
```

So change the two entries which have "ShellExtensionX64.dll" to "ShellExtensionU.dll". Since ShellExtensionU.dll is the 32 bit. Save, run the Register.bat file.

Now it will show up in the Everything tool. Downside is it won't show up in the Windows Explorer. If you need that fixed then the workaround is to install "WOW64Menu".